# Outlook Addin: Dialog: Office.js is loaded outside of office client” in dialog popup - IE and Edge

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

**Background**

Currently, I have a Outlook Addin, completely functional in Outlook Thick Client, OWA on Chrome and Firefox.

**Problem(s)**

on IE Edge and IE 11 (Owa Only)
I have following problems :

- When the control goes from my page opened in the dialog popup to the 3rd party login provider the DialogClosing related code triggers with code 12009 code.
  Although the popup is still open.
- Office.js loaded outside of office client 
  [image: Office.js loaded outside of office client]

  This is when the control passes from the my site to the authentication site say (login.live.com) and back to my redirect script (the popup open script and the redirect script both hosted on the same domain) where I try and extract the code that is passed.

Things work as expected in every other browser except the Edge and IE.

**Show me the code (Snippet)**

```
        // height and width are percentages of the size of the screen.
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(fullUrl, {height: 45, width: 55, displayInIframe: false},
            function (asyncResult) {
            console.log(asyncResult);
            if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {

                LogMessage(LOG_MESSAGES.DISPLAY_DIALOG_ASYNC_FAILED + " Error: " + asyncResult.error.code + " " + asyncResult.error.message);

                //Error code 12009 means "user chose to ignore the dialog box"
                if (asyncResult.error.code === 12009) {
                    authenticationFailure();
                } else {
                    myLogin();
                }
            } else {
                dialog = asyncResult.value;
                dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, handleToken);
                dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, dialogClosing);

                LogMessage(LOG_MESSAGES.DISPLAY_DIALOG_ASYNC_SUCCEED);
            }
        });
```

**Protected Mode:**

On by Default.
While going over other answers it seems this is related to protected mode. 
I turned off and re-tested in Edge but the problem remains.
In IE11 however the issue got resolved.

**Any other info?**

Yes, The pop window opens and immediately goes off focus for some reason in both IE and Edge.

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this error. Are you using old-OWA or new-OWA (option which appears on right hand corner: Try the new outlook)? Are addin, popup script and redirect url in same domain?

Comment: Can you please share the IE/Edge Version where you are facing this issue.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT: I am using live.com. Microsoft Edge version 40.15063.674.0 -> Microsoft EdgeHTML 15.15063

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I am experiencing the same issue. It occurs for **Windows 10 Pro v1903 - Edge 44.18362.387.0**. However _it does not_ occur for **Windows 10 Pro v1803 - Edge 42.17134.1.0**